# Solving a system of differential algebraic equations (DAE)

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration

I am trying to solve a system of 8 differential algebraic equations, where equations 3 and 5 are differential equations and the rest are constraints which need to be satisfied. Also I only know the initial condition $y[0]=b/r$, so I am letting Mathematica find the consistent initial conditions.

Using `NDSolve` gives me an error:

> NDSolveValue::index: The DAE solver failed at x = 0. The solver is intended for index 1 DAE systems and structural analysis indicates that the DAE index is 3. The option `Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic}` may be used to reduce the index of the system.

---

Since I have constraints (invariants) I also tried `Method -> "Projection"` but it gives me error:

> NDSolve::initf:  The initialization of the method NDSolve`StateSpace failed.

How can I solve this problem using Projection methods or any other in Mathematica?

```
(*Defining parameters*)
param = {a -> 0.072, b -> 0.04, r -> 0.05, ρ -> 0.06, σ -> 0.1, τ ->  1/3, α -> 0.1};

(*Defining variables to be evaluated*)
vars = {y, RM, sxx, sy, mxx, my, R, λ};

(*Defining the system to be solved, differential equations and constraints (invariants)*)
in1 = RM[x] -(1-Exp[(my[x] + σ*sy[x] - 1/2*(σ + sy[x])^2)τ + (σ + sy[x])*InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], α]*Sqrt[τ]]); 
in2 = sxx[x] - (1/RM[x] - 1)*(σ + sy[x]);
eq3 = sy[x] == sxx[x]*D[y[x], x]/y[x]; 
in4 = mxx[x] -(  1/RM[x]*a/  y[x] - ρ + (1/RM[x] - 1)*(my[x] + σ*sy[x] - R[x]) + (1 - 1/RM[x])*(σ + sy[x])^2);
eq5 = my[x] == D[y[x], x]/y[x]*mxx[x] + 1/2*D[y[x], {x, 2}]/y[x]*(sxx[x])^2; in6 = (r*(1 - x) + ρ*x)*  y[x] -( a*x/RM[x] + (1 - x/RM[x])*b); 
in7 = b/y[x] + my[x] + σ*sy[x] - R[x] - (1 - x/RM[x])/( 1 - x)*(σ + sy[x])^2;
in8 = a/y[x] + my[x] + σ*sy[x] - R[x] -( 1/RM[x]*(σ + sy[x])^2 + λ[x]*y[x]*RM[x]);

eqall = {in1==0, in2==0, eq3, in4==0, eq5, in6==0, in7==0, in8==0} /. param;

inv = {in1 == 0, in2 == 0, in4 == 0, in6 == 0, in7 == 0, in8 == 0} /. param;
```

Here is the solution part:

```
(*Finding consistent initial conditions*)

init = NDSolve[eqall, vars, {x, 0, 0}];
value = First[{y[x], y'[x], y''[x], RM[x], sxx[x], sy[x], mxx[x], my[x], R[x], λ[x]} /. init /. x -> 0]


(*Using NDSolve*)
sol = NDSolve[{eqall, y[0] == value[[1]], y'[0] == value[[2]], y''[0] == value[[3]], RM[0] == value[[4]], sxx[0] == value[[5]], sy[0] == value[[6]], mxx[0] == value[[7]], my[0] == value[[8]],  R[0] == value[[9]]}, vars, {x, 0, 1}];

(*Using NDSolve Projection Methods*)
Prosol = NDSolve[{eqall, start}, vars, {x, 0, 1}, Method -> {"Projection", Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta",  "Invariants" -> inv}, InterpolationOrder -> Automatic]
```

[image: DAE]

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You did not input initial value for $Lambda$ in sol